# Which is more grammatically correct - "performance in" or "performance on"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, prepositions, word-usage, in-on

Which of the following is more grammatically correct?

a. John's performance on the test shocked the teacher.

(or)

b. John's performance in the test shocked the teacher.

Answer (score 4):

I think if it is a written test, we most often say *performance on the test* (maybe because we "put our ideas down on paper"), but if it is measuring abilities in an environment, e.g. response times, or skill comparisons (before and after, etc) we use *performance in the test*.

> Methods used in learning to drive and performance [in](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01441649308716855?journalCode=ttrv20) the driving test in Great Britain
>   The test result, a flame spread index, essentially compares the performance in the test to that of red oak.
>   The smaller the wear scar, the better the performance in the test. (of [motor oil](http://www.amsoil.com/lit/g3115.pdf))
>
> As a final step in the test redesign process, USCIS conducted a series of records studies to evaluate applicant performance [on](http://www.uscis.gov/us-citizenship/naturalization-test/applicant-performance-naturalization-test) the test (us.gov)
>   ...performance [on](http://www.nasponline.org/communications/spawareness/testscores.pdf) the test of reading comprehension is equal to an age equivalent of 8.7 years and a grade equivalent of 2.6...
>   Student performance [on](http://schools.nyc.gov/NR/rdonlyres/B40055DD-A3E5-48C2-BA64-51664C27EFDA/0/UnderstandingtheISRMath102113MY.pdf) the test is translated into an overall Scale Score.

Answer (score 3):

Performance really depends on the object:  You perform IN a play but you perform ON a stage so:

```
His performance in the play was enjoyable.

His performance on the stage was enjoyable.
```

So really your question comes down to: do you perform on a test? Do you perform in a test? I would lead towards "on" because of other usage:

```
His grade on the test was 90%.

Your third answer on the test was incorrect.
```

Then again, if we are really talking about an implied "performance *in taking*" the test, suddenly this could be correct:

```
 John's performance in (taking) the test shocked the teacher.
```

However I would also go ahead and call both of them "awkward". I would avoid entirely and use

```
John's performance during the test shocked the teacher.
```

Or best of all, use K.I.S.S. and avoid the problem altogether:

```
 John's test performance shocked the teacher.
```

Comment: I would have to agree that both in and on seem strange. The last suggestion would probably be the form that I would go for. However if you really need to use one or the other, as Digital Chris said, *on* would be the one.

Comment: I agree with all of the above except that I would interpret *John's performance during the test shocked the teacher* as meaning he flipped out/behaved badly.

Comment: @Susan what if it was a test for a dance class?

Comment: @Chris - you are absolutely correct there. I guess it really depends **on** the test.  ;) +1